# Only get Time From Date Time for comparisons

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(s.start_time at time zone 'Asia/Singapore','HH24:MI:SS PM')  AS roster_starttime,
    TO_CHAR(c.time_server at time zone 'Asia/Singapore','HH24:MI:SS PM') AS Clock_TIme,
    TO_CHAR(((c.time_server at time zone 'Asia/Singapore')::time - (s.start_time at time zone 'Asia/Singapore')::Time ),'HH "Hours" MI "minutes"') AS lateness_minutes
FROM
    employee_info e
INNER JOIN
    shifts s ON s.employee_id = e.employee
INNER JOIN
    clock c ON c.shift = s.id
```

Someone messed up the shifts date but the time is correct so I want to just get the time from both `c.time_server` and `s.start_time`. And subtract them to get the time if someone was late that day (`lateness_minutes`).

Here's a sample result when I do it in my end

[image]

Shouldnt this just be 11 minutes? how can I fix this issue?

Comment: `time_server::time`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply cast the `timestamp` to either `date` or `time`, e.g.

```
SELECT 
  '2021-09-17 10:30:47'::time,
  '2021-09-17 10:30:47'::date,
  to_char('2021-09-17 10:30:47'::time,'HH "Hours" MI "minutes"');

   time   |    date    |       to_char           
----------+------------+---------------------
 10:30:47 | 2021-09-17 | 10 Hours 30 minutes
(1 Zeile)
```